# Why does dG delete only one line of text in VIM?

Tags: vim

Instead delete text to end of file, <kbd>d</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> delete only one line of text in VIM on my computer.

What might go wrong?

Comment: Start by disabling vimrc (`vim -u NONE`). If the problem goes away, start deleting chunks of your `~/.vimrc` and try again without the `-u NONE` until the problem goes away.

Comment: I would start by looking at `:verbose map G?` before deleting stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You can quickly execute the command without mappings via `:normal!` (note the `!`):

```
:normal! dG
```

If that works (it should), the culprit is a mapping. You can check via

```
:verbose nmap d
:verbose omap G
```

(`d` is invoked from *normal mode* and this enters *operator-pending mode*.)

The command will also tell you where the bad mapping is defined, so that you can remove / correct it.